# Angular 5 wildcard path matching

Tags: angular, routes, angular5

I'm learning Angular 5 and I'm trying to get more firm grasp on routing. My app is consuming a REST API, which in the returned DTOs provides URLs to detailed information about objects. The structure of the path is constant `/Categories/root-category/subcategory-1/subcategory-2/.../subcategory-N/p/{product-code}` The problematic part for me is that the depth of the category tree waries, there may be any number of the subcategories beetwen the root category and the product attatched to the leaf of the tree.

I've checked multiple tutorials including the official Hero trail, but in the ones that I've found the examples use simple URL patterns know beforehand, which does not work for me, because I can't predict how deep the category tree will be. What I also want to avoid, is to manipulate / construct custom urls, based on the returned ones.

An example code:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Categories', children: [
      {
        path: ':categoryId', component: CategoryComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '**/p/:productCode', component: ProductDetailsComponent}
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

It matches the path for the `CategoryComponent`, but failes to do so for the `ProductDetailsComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [

   { path: 'Categories', CategoriesComponent

      children: [

         { path: ':id', component: CategoryComponent  

            children: [

               { path: ':name/p/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent }

            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Failes with the message, that Angular cannot match any path.